# Changing the value of KeepAlive in azure function app which uses azure signalR

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, azure-signalr

My app is an Azure Functions app and I am using Azure SignalR in it. I want to decrease the time of KeepAlive for this app. For web apps, I know that we can change KeepAlive interval like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    });
}
```

But how to change the interval in an azure functions app which uses signalR?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [`functionTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) global configuration option in your "host.json" file to decrease the function app timeout. The timeout can be set to minimum of 1 second to maximum according to the plan type. See [`functionTimeout` per plan type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pop0q.png).

You can find additional information regarding the timeout [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout).

This document regarding [Azure Functions and Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions) can be be helpful as well.